# Unable to open Encrypted Database in Sqlite Manager

Tags: android, database, encryption, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

I have followed this tutorial [How to implement SQLcipher in Android](http://blog.webandapp-solution.de/sqlcipher-for-android-tutorial-encrypt-and-backup-sqlite-databasepart1/) and implemented SQLcipher over my existing SQLite application, It works well. I was able to Insert, Fetch records from the database (Like normal SQLite application). However when i exported the database and tried to open it using SQlite Manager (I use Windows System) it asked me for password (Which is the actual need of encryption) but its not accepting the password which i used to encrypt.It keeps prompting the password.[image]

Comment: You may want to verify what version of SQLCipher was used to create your database, versus the version of SQLCipher being used within SQLiteManager.  If they are not the same, `PRAGMA` commands may be required to allow for reading the database file.  You can contact SQLabs SQLiteManager here: http://www.sqlabs.com/contact.php

Comment: Thank you @NickParker I will post back after trying with Older versions of SQLite Manager! Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much @NickParker I have updated SQLcipher.jar used in my project and it worked!!

Comment: Really working,Thankyou Mr.Arun and Mr.Nick.